NestJS. Get Validation Error when I send correct body
Here is my Pipe. When I send not correct body, validation work. But when I send correct body, I get Validation Error ([Nest] 15132 ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Validation error
Error)
import { ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common'
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer'
import { validate } from 'class-validator'
import { ValidationException } from 'src/exceptions/validation.exception'

@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
    async transform(value: any, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<any> {
        const body = plainToInstance(metatype, value)
        const errors = await validate(body)
        const badPassword = !/(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).+/.test(body.password)
        if (errors.length > 0 || badPassword) {
            const message = errors.map(
                error =>
                    `${error.property} - ${Object.values(error.constraints).join(', ')}`
            )
            if (badPassword)
                message.push(`password - should contains chars and numbers both`)
            throw new ValidationException(message)
        }
        return value
    }
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
